# PYTHON: Error Message in random.py? Used to work, then it didn't, then it did, now it doesn't again. What's happening?

Tags: python, random

I've been learning python for a few months now, and usually I've been able to overcome all the problems I face, but now I'm at a loss. I'm writing a program called 'Quizzer' that will be used to generate random questions based on lists of terms and answers that Python is given.
My main problem has with the the gen_question function I've been working on. I wanted Python to receive a term, and output four multiple choice answers: One the actual, and three randomly selected from the pool of all possible answers. I had to include several checks to make sure the selected random answers were not the real answer and were not the same as each other.

I finally got it to work today, and then a bit later I tested it. I got an error message (that I will display in a second). I undid everything back to where I was earlier and I still got the same error message. After a few hours I came back, and I got it again. Out of frustration, I retried, and it worked. Now it isn't working anymore. Please, anyone: What is going on?

Here is my code (I don't know what's necessary so I am including the entire thing):

```
#import random for generating
import random

#term and definition libraries
terms_ans ={'term1':'answer1','term2':'answer2','term3':'answer3','term4':'answer4','term5':'answer5','term6':'answer6','term7':'answer7','term8':'answer8','term9':'answer9','term10':'answer10','term11':'answer11','term12':'answer12','term13':'answer13','term14':'answer14','term15':'answer15','term16':'answer16','term17':'answer17','term18':'answer18','term19':'answer19','term20':'answer20'}
term_list = ['term1','term2','term3','term4','term5','term6','term7','term8','term9','term10','term11','term12','term13','term14','term15','term16','term17','term18','term19','term20']
answer_list = ['answer1','answer2','answer3','answer4','answer5','answer6','answer7','answer8','answer9','answer10','answer11','answer12','answer13','answer14','answer15','answer16','answer17','answer18','answer19','answer20']

#picks the test questions to ask
def gen_test(amount=len(term_list)):
    found_starter = False
    test_terms = []
    while found_starter == False:
        #pick a random starting point in the terms to see if it is suitable
        start_point = random.randint(1, len(term_list))
        if amount == len(term_list):
            #if user inputs max amount of questions possible, just take the term list
            test_terms = term_list
            found_starter = True
        elif len(term_list) - (start_point + amount) >= 0:
            #if it is suitable, then append the terms to the test questions
            for x in xrange(start_point,start_point+amount):
                test_terms.append(term_list[x])
            found_starter = True
    else:
        return test_terms

#scramble list
def list_scrambler(unscrambled_list):
    test_terms=[]
    countdown = len(unscrambled_list) + 1
    for x in range(1, countdown):
        transfer_var = random.randint(0,len(unscrambled_list)-1)
        test_terms.append(unscrambled_list[transfer_var])
        del unscrambled_list[transfer_var]
    return test_terms

#ask user for amount of questions needed and get the list
test_terms = list_scrambler(gen_test(int(raw_input("How many questions on your test? (There are " + str(len(term_list)) + " questions in total.) "))))



def gen_question(picked_term, question_num=1, total_amount=len(test_terms)):
    #print start of question
    print
    print "Question " + str(question_num) + " of " + str(total_amount) + ":"
    print
    print picked_term
    print
    #gather random multiple choice answers they must a) all be different and b) not be the answer
    ans_1_acceptable = False
    while ans_1_acceptable == False:
        int_rand_ans_1 = random.randint(1, len(term_list)) - 1
        if str(term_list[int_rand_ans_1]) != str(picked_term):
            #Term accepted; send to output
            ans_1_acceptable = True
    ans_2_acceptable = False
    while ans_2_acceptable == False:
        int_rand_ans_2 = random.randint(1, len(term_list)) - 1
        if int_rand_ans_2 != int_rand_ans_1 and str(term_list[int_rand_ans_2]) != str(picked_term):
            ans_2_acceptable = True
    ans_3_acceptable = False
    while ans_3_acceptable == False:
        int_rand_ans_3 = random.randint(1, len(term_list)) - 1
        if int_rand_ans_3 != int_rand_ans_1 and int_rand_ans_3 != int_rand_ans_2 and str(term_list[int_rand_ans_3]) != str(picked_term):
            ans_3_acceptable = True
    #Decide if the correct answer is A, B, C, or D
    correct_ans = random.randint(1,4)
    #Print the options using the variables gathered above
    if correct_ans != 1:
        print "A) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_1]
    else:
        print "A) " + terms_ans[picked_term]
    if correct_ans != 2:
        print "B) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_2]
    else:
        print "B) " + terms_ans[picked_term]
    if correct_ans != 3:
        print "C) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_3]
    else:
        print "C) " + terms_ans[picked_term]
    if correct_ans == 1:
        print "D) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_1]
    elif correct_ans == 2:
        print "D) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_2]
    elif correct_ans == 3:
        print "D) " + answer_list[int_rand_ans_3]
    else:
        print "D) " + terms_ans[picked_term]

    print
```

Now, usually it outputs everything like you'd expect. I don't have a feature to automatically generate questions yet so I have to type in the line:

```
gen_question('term1')
```

or whatever term I'm using.

Here is the output I've been getting:

```
How many questions on your test? (There are 20 questions in total.) 20
>>> gen_question('term1')

Question 1 of 20:

term1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    gen_question('term1')
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\LEARNING PYTHON\scripts\in progress\Quizzer.py", line 69, in gen_question
    int_rand_ans_1 = random.randint(1, len(term_list)) - 1
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\LEARNING PYTHON\python 2.7.5\lib\random.py", line 241, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\LEARNING PYTHON\python 2.7.5\lib\random.py", line 217, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
>>> gen_question('term8')
```

Comment: Change `test_terms = term_list` to `test_terms = term_list[:]` and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: @peter It did, awesome. A changed the code around a bit to make it look less like, well what I wrote up above, but I still had a bit of an issue with it eating up my term_list, and what you said fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty obvious that `randint()` is complaining because `term_list` is empty, right?  Then

```
random.randint(1, len(term_list))
```

is

```
random.randint(1, 0)
```

and `randint` is stuck.  So *why* is `term_list` empty?  It's because this statement:

```
test_terms = list_scrambler(gen_test(int(raw_input("How many questions on your test? (There are " + str(len(term_list)) + " questions in total.) "))))
```

destroys `term_list`, and that's probably ;-) not intended.

It's hard to follow the code to track down why that happens.  The basic problem is that `gen_test` can set

```
test_terms = term_list
```

and then end up returning `term_list` under the name `test_terms`.  Then `term_list` is still intact at the start of `list_scrambler`, but empty by the time `list_scrambler` ends.  The

```
        del unscrambled_list[transfer_var]
```

deletes all the elements in `term_list`, one at a time.

Comment: Awesome, it works now. I completely changed a lot of the code to make it look less messy, but my term_list kept getting eaten up like you said. Writing `term_list = list_of_terms[:]` (I had to change around some variable names) seemed to fix it right up, as a comment above suggested. It works like clockwork now! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what is getting you:

```
term_list = [...]
```

is defined at the start of your file, but later on you do the following when the amount entered is the max.

```
test_term = term_list
```

This does not create a copy of your array, this creates two variables which both **reference** the same array.  So any further modifications to `test_term` are actually reflected against the list referenced by both variables.

And since you are defining `test_terms` at a global level in the script you NUKE it when you make this call

```
def list_scrambler(unscrambled_list):
    test_terms=[]
    countdown = len(unscrambled_list) + 1
    for x in range(1, countdown):
        transfer_var = random.randint(0,len(unscrambled_list)-1)
        test_terms.append(unscrambled_list[transfer_var])
        del unscrambled_list[transfer_var]
    return test_terms
```

Also to add,

Hungarian notation is a big no-no and python is a strongly typed language anyways.  If you are having a hard time keeping track of times don't rely on variable names.  Instead get yourself an IDE or use names expressive of what they are doing.

```
if something == false:
```

should be rewritten as

```
if not something
```

This one is more for preference, but when printing out text that needs to have data floated in, you can save yourself some headache and write

```
"D) {0}".format(somelist[index])
```

This will stuff the variable into the {0} and provides you with some formatting context and prevents you from having to `str()` an object.

Also, globals in general are considered a ***bad*** thing, they're debatable.  like globals in *C* sometimes they serve a clear purpose, but for the most part they hide bugs and make issues harder to track.  Also sometimes your variable declarations will shadow globals, others (as you saw) will let you screw things up.

Comment: I think I am understanding some of what you are saying, but what is `"D) {0}".format(somelist[index])` ? is that creating a dictionary with the answer inside? (By the way, the code is fixed now. I redid everything but the list scrambler and made it much less jumbled.)

Comment: @user3043902 this formats the string by inserting your values into the `{}` curly braces.  `"Hello {0}".format("world")` becomes `"Hello world"` and `"Hello {0}, The Date is {1}".format("John", now())` becomes `"Hello John, the Date is 12/8/2013"` it's a nice way to format a string without having to do all of the "somestring" + str(variable) + "another str"...etc tedium!

Comment: oh ok, thanks. The way the book I'm reading said to format a string is "Hello %s" % ("world") to get the same thing.